# Session Control Java - GET Cookie from Request and Pass it to POST request

Tags: java, cookies, jersey, realm

I am actually stuck in a data fetching API. In its documentation it has been mentioned that I have to make a call to the login API first then using its Authorization header and cookie (returned in Login API response) I have to make subsequent calls (keeping session control).

The first call is successful and I have received the Cookie i.e. X-SESSIONID and Authorization Header from response Headers. But the subsequent call is returning: **401 Unauthorized** even I am passing session Id and authorization header.

May be I am doing something wrong in session management or making subsequent call. Can someone help?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.ws.rs.core.*;
import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.*;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.*;
import com.sun.jersey.api.*;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;

public class DigestClient {

    // Dividing into two parts because we need to send the last part of uri in our
    // second request to service.
    static String baseUri = "http://data.crea.ca";
    static String subUri = "/Login.svc/Login";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException, IOException {

        ClientConfig cc = new DefaultClientConfig();
        Client client = Client.create(cc);

        WebResource webResource = client.resource(baseUri + subUri);
        ClientResponse response = webResource.get(ClientResponse.class);
        // Basically in Digest-Authentication mechanism, we hit the rest service two
        // times.
        // First time with No Authentication, which returns some values (qop, nonce,
        // realm) which are used as inputs in second call to rest service.

        /*--------------- First call-----------------*/
        // We get 401, Unauthorized
        System.out.println(response.getStatus() );
        // Here is the complete header information
        System.out.println(response.getHeaders());
        // We need "WWW-Authenticate" part information for our second call to rest
        System.out.println("WWW-Authenticate: \t" + response.getHeaders().get("www-Authenticate"));

        String noAuthResp = response.getHeaders().get("www-Authenticate").toString();
        noAuthResp = noAuthResp.replace("Digest ", "");
        noAuthResp = noAuthResp.replace('[', '{');
        noAuthResp = noAuthResp.replace(']', '}');

        // Creating a JSONObject for easy information retrieval
        JSONObject resp = new JSONObject(noAuthResp);

        /*--------------- Second call-----------------*/
        // Here client has to set the fields which was returned from the first call
        String user = "CXLHfDVrziCfvwgCuL8nUahC"; // username
        String password = "mFqMsCSPdnb5WO1gpEEtDCHH"; // password
        String realm = resp.getString("realm"); // realm value from the first rest-call response
        String qop = resp.getString("qop"); // qop value from the first rest-call response
        String nonce = resp.getString("nonce"); // nonce value from the first rest-call response
        String opaque = "";//resp.getString("opaque"); // Some times if we don't get this value, set it with ""
        String algorithm = "MD5"; // The algorithm set by the client
        int nonceCount = 678; // Some numerical input from the client
        String clientNonce = "afdjas0"; // Some random text from the client for encryption

        String method = "GET"; // HTTP method

        String ha1 = new DigestClient().formHA1(user, realm, password);
        String ha2 = new DigestClient().formHA2(method, subUri);
        String responseCode = new DigestClient().generateResponse(ha1, nonce, nonceCount, clientNonce, qop, ha2);

        // Header to be sent to the service
        String value = "Digest username=\"" + user + "\", realm=\"" + realm + "\", nonce=\"" + nonce + "\", uri=\""
                + subUri + "\", qop=" + qop + ", nc=" + nonceCount + ", cnonce=\"" + clientNonce + "\", response=\""
                + responseCode + "\", opaque=\"" + opaque + "\"";

        System.out.println("Digest Header: " + value );
        
        // Hitting the service
        response = webResource.header("authorization", value).type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).accept("*")
                .get(ClientResponse.class);
        System.out.println("\nComplete Response:\n" + response + "\n");
        String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> responseHeaders = response.getHeaders();
        
        System.out.println("Response header: " + prepareParameters(responseHeaders).toString());
        System.out.println("Cookie: " +  response.getCookies().get(1).toString());
    //  System.out.println("Response Text: " + output);
        
    String sessionId = response.getCookies().get(1).toString();

    
    /****************************SUBSEQUENT CALL (WHERE I AM PASSING SESSION ID AS COOKIE AND AUTHORIZATION HEADER ***************************/
    
    
        System.out.println("Getting metadata..");
        System.out.println("SessionID: " + sessionId.split(";")[0]);
        System.out.println("Digest Header: " + value);
        
        String sid = sessionId.split(";")[0];
        String request = "<Employee><Name>Sunil</Name></<Employee>";

        webResource = client.resource("http://data.crea.ca/Metadata.svc/GetMetadata");
        ClientResponse response2 = webResource.get(ClientResponse.class);
        
        response2 = webResource.header("authorization", value).header("Cookie", sid).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).accept("*")
                .post(ClientResponse.class, request);
        
        if (response2.getStatus() != 200) {
            System.out.println("MetaDataError: " + response2.getStatus());
        }
        
        String output2 = response2.getEntity(String.class);
        

//      
//      URL url = new URL("http://data.crea.ca/Metadata.svc/GetMetadata");
//      HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
//
//      // Set timeout as per needs
//      connection.setConnectTimeout(20000);
//      connection.setReadTimeout(20000);
//
//      // Set DoOutput to true if you want to use URLConnection for output.
//      // Default is false
//      connection.setDoOutput(true);
//
//      connection.setUseCaches(true);
//      connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
//
//      // Set Headers
//      connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
//      connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");
//      connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", value);
//      connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", sid);
//      
//      // Write XML
//      OutputStream outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
//      byte[] b = request.getBytes("UTF-8");
//      outputStream.write(b);
//      outputStream.flush();
//      outputStream.close();
//
//      // Read XML
//      InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
//      byte[] res = new byte[2048];
//      int i = 0;
//      StringBuilder response2 = new StringBuilder();
//      while ((i = inputStream.read(res)) != -1) {
//          response2.append(new String(res, 0, i));
//      }
//      inputStream.close();

        System.out.println("Response of metadata= " + output2.toString());      
        

        
        
        //getMetadata( response.getCookies().get(1).toString(), value);
        
    }

    public static void getMetadata(String sessionId, String header) throws IOException {
        
        System.out.println("Getting metadata..");
        System.out.println("SessionID: " + sessionId.split(";")[0]);
        System.out.println("Digest Header: " + header);
        
        String sid = sessionId.split(";")[0];
        String request = "<Employee><Name>Sunil</Name></<Employee>";

        URL url = new URL("http://data.crea.ca/Metadata.svc/GetMetadata");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Set timeout as per needs
        connection.setConnectTimeout(20000);
        connection.setReadTimeout(20000);

        // Set DoOutput to true if you want to use URLConnection for output.
        // Default is false
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        connection.setUseCaches(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        // Set Headers
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", header);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", sid);
        
        // Write XML
        OutputStream outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
        byte[] b = request.getBytes("UTF-8");
        outputStream.write(b);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

        // Read XML
        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        byte[] res = new byte[2048];
        int i = 0;
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        while ((i = inputStream.read(res)) != -1) {
            response.append(new String(res, 0, i));
        }
        inputStream.close();

        System.out.println("Response of metadata= " + response.toString());     
        
    }
    
    private static Map<String,String> prepareParameters(MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParameters) {

           Map<String,String> parameters = new HashMap<String,String>();

           for(String str : queryParameters.keySet()){
             parameters.put(str, queryParameters.getFirst(str));
           }
           return parameters;

            }
    
    // For generating HA1 value
    public String formHA1(String userName, String realm, String password) {
        String ha1 = DigestUtils.md5Hex(userName + ":" + realm + ":" + password);
        return ha1;
    }

    // For generating HA2 value
    public String formHA2(String method, String uri) {
        String ha2 = DigestUtils.md5Hex(method + ":" + uri);
        return ha2;
    }

    // For generating response at client side
    public String generateResponse(String ha1, String nonce, int nonceCount, String clientNonce, String qop,
            String ha2) {
        String response = DigestUtils
                .md5Hex(ha1 + ":" + nonce + ":" + nonceCount + ":" + clientNonce + ":" + qop + ":" + ha2);
        return response;

    }
}
```

**Output**

```
401
{Cache-Control=[private], Server=[Microsoft-IIS/10.0], WWW-Authenticate=[Digest realm="CREA.Distribution", nonce="NjM3ODQ5NTI2NzgzNjk6OTRmMjM0NDJlMmVkZGY0MDI1YmE0MzkxNTM5NDhhNmY=", qop="auth"], X-AspNet-Version=[4.0.30319], Set-Cookie=[ARRAffinity=eb0215f43a7fdf079429ba39da6cd0de66afa6b4085fd1016024d539de9de1b3;Path=/;HttpOnly;Domain=data.crea.ca, ASP.NET_SessionId=y5ylejdp2f5q3siitg410lk5; path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax], Content-Length=[0], Date=[Thu, 07 Apr 2022 18:24:38 GMT], X-Powered-By=[ASP.NET], Content-Type=[application/xml; charset=utf-8]}
WWW-Authenticate:   [Digest realm="CREA.Distribution", nonce="NjM3ODQ5NTI2NzgzNjk6OTRmMjM0NDJlMmVkZGY0MDI1YmE0MzkxNTM5NDhhNmY=", qop="auth"]
Digest Header: Digest username="CXLHfDVrziCfvwgCuL8nUahC", realm="CREA.Distribution", nonce="NjM3ODQ5NTI2NzgzNjk6OTRmMjM0NDJlMmVkZGY0MDI1YmE0MzkxNTM5NDhhNmY=", uri="/Login.svc/Login", qop=auth, nc=678, cnonce="afdjas0", response="f7d2445a27173c5e876e3b2833369e64", opaque=""

Complete Response:
GET http://data.crea.ca/Login.svc/Login returned a response status of 200 OK

Response header: {RETS-Request-ID=, Cache-Control=private, Server=Microsoft-IIS/10.0, X-AspNet-Version=4.0.30319, Set-Cookie=ARRAffinity=eb0215f43a7fdf079429ba39da6cd0de66afa6b4085fd1016024d539de9de1b3;Path=/;HttpOnly;Domain=data.crea.ca, RETS-Version=RETS/1.7.2, Content-Length=591, Date=Thu, 07 Apr 2022 18:24:38 GMT, X-Powered-By=ASP.NET, Content-Type=text/xml}
Cookie: X-SESSIONID=95b7bcc5-6d47-4494-936b-5bfaf3485679;Version=1
Getting metadata..
SessionID: X-SESSIONID=95b7bcc5-6d47-4494-936b-5bfaf3485679
Digest Header: Digest username="CXLHfDVrziCfvwgCuL8nUahC", realm="CREA.Distribution", nonce="NjM3ODQ5NTI2NzgzNjk6OTRmMjM0NDJlMmVkZGY0MDI1YmE0MzkxNTM5NDhhNmY=", uri="/Login.svc/Login", qop=auth, nc=678, cnonce="afdjas0", response="f7d2445a27173c5e876e3b2833369e64", opaque=""
MetaDataError: 401
Response of metadata=
```